# How do I build multi skipper on pandas automatically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for asking to simple, on mongoDB usually the function that work is [Skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/), but I get lost when looking pandas equivalent.  My pandas query 1st-1000th for is

```
list1 = a['id'].head(1000)
```

But, I want to query the 1001st-2000th entry , 2001st-3000th entry, etc.

I'm expected the answer to be saved as `df1`, `df2`, ... , `dfn`

How suppose I do this?

Comment: `.head(2000).tail(1000)` works, but probably isn't optimal

Comment: Thanks, at least it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `//` and `groupby`, and save your data frame into a `list`

```
l = [x for _,x in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//1000)]
```

Update

```
variables = locals()
for i,j in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//1000):
    variables["df{0}".format(i+1)] = j
```

Comment: Great, that is what I want, my data is 25600 rows, can you save them to `df1`, ...., `df26` ?

Comment: @NabihBawazir you can create a dict for that like `d={y:x for y,x in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//1000)}` and get the data frame like d[0],d[1]....

Comment: That is not split the output to multiple dataframe

Comment: best answer selected

Comment: @Wen - No, dont do this, dictionary is way [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5037218)

Comment: @jezrael I list dict method for him in the comment ...since he is asking for split it to dataframe ..

Answer (score 4):

You can use `iloc` function, and please remember that indices are zero based

```
a.iloc[0:1000,]
a.iloc[1000:2000,]
```

iloc will allow you to filter like this

Comment: Oh my god, it just `iloc`, I forget about this function

Comment: Indices are zero based. `[:1000]` or `[0:1000]`, and `[1000:2000]`